# i am trying to upload multiple files using ajax - not working in some cases

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i am trying to upload multiple files

i am using ajax

the problem is that sometimes the uploading is not working

and i am not sure about the reload function  reloadtabeladeanexos()

after the upload i am doing a query to mysql and show the uploaded files names and urls on a html table

in my pc i am using chrome and works , but some times when i open a new form it fails to upload the first time if i reload mannualy and try again the upload works well

```
function reloadtabeladeanexos() {
       // location.reload();
               $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href,
            headers: {
                "Pragma": "no-cache",
                "Expires": -1,
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
            }
        }).done(function () {
            window.location.reload(true);
        });
    }

    function uploadFile(){



            var input = document.getElementById("file1");

            for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) { 
            //alert(input.files.length);

            var file = _("file1").files[i];
            var idc =<?php echo $pid; ?>;
            var ponto=16;
            var iddoafme=<?php echo $r_id; ?>;

           // alert(<?php echo $pid; ?>);
            //alert(ponto);
            //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file1", file);
            formdata.append("idc", idc);
            formdata.append("ponto", ponto);
            formdata.append("iddoafme", iddoafme);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
        //ajax.open("POST", "upload.php?idc="+$r_idc+");
            ajax.open("POST", "uploadponto16.php");
        ajax.send(formdata);

            reloadtabeladeanexos();
            }
    }

    function progressHandler(event){
        _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
        var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
        _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
    }
    function completeHandler(event){
        _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
        _("progressBar").value = 0;
            reloadtabeladeanexos();
    }
    function errorHandler(event){
        _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
    }
    function abortHandler(event){
        _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";

    }
```

Comment: Did you check console log, when upload fails? Is there any error message?

Comment: no errors on the console, in my PC its working , but some other using chrome also,its not working , to show the file uploaded they have to manually reload or refresh the page